# put array data to input field and submit that data in model as separate records

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, view

I am using code igniter and I have an array which coming from a java script function in view file and I want to get it to a form to save in the db after submitting data.After submitting it is going to controller ->model function using post and then it save after some if conditions.Here my question is how we can get that array into some input fields to pass in post method and how we have to define it.

In view file function

```
function my_function{
//after some codes

const my_array =[];
}
```

the output of this array is

```
0:{a:'1',b:'2',c:'35'}
1:{a:'2',b:'3',c:'34'}
2:{a:'5',b:'1',c:'87'}
3:{a:'4',b:'3',c:'90'}
```

it should come here in readonly mode

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="a" id="a" name= "a" class="form-control name-pull-image">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="b" id="b" name= "b" class="form-control name-pull-image">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="c" id="c" name= "c" class="form-control name-pull-image">
</div>
</div>
```

And this should be save in db as separate records after clicking submit.

How I can implement this?
and how i can pass this to the controller?to take it to the model

Answer (score 0):

what exactly your model needed?? I got your question, but am not sure to answer, it's might be wrong. But how about this:

Your html form must be like this, to pass an array to the controller:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="a" id="a" name= "a[]" value="a" class="form-control name-pull-image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="b" id="b" name= "b[]" value="b" class="form-control name-pull-image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class ="c" id="c" name= "c[]" value="c" class="form-control name-pull-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

And get the array when form submitted:

```
<?php
// your controller...
public function formSubmit() {
    $form_data = [];
    for ( $i=0; $i < count($this->input->post('a')); $++ ) {
        array_push($form_data, [
             'a' => $this->input->post('a')[$i],
             'b' => $this->input->post('b')[$i],
             'c' => $this->input->post('c')[$i],
        ]);
    }
    // result
    print_r($form_data);
}
// other code...
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering.Simply I have two forms and from first form the array is passing to the next form by next button .And then after submitting the second form only that array should go to the model anyhow.The form is already having action url that mentioned the controller.So what I want is to pass this array to that model after submitting the form but that array is in a javascript function.

Comment: In this answer how can I show array data in the view and how can i get that same data to model

Comment: You can use [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api to process the next call with other controller method. In that method you can modeling the data as you want. Then save it into database. Is that form wizard? CMIIW